# Plot Location vs. Time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, charts, maps

I'm working on a simulation where workers will be tracked as they walk around a store.  I'd like to create a map showing a line where the person has been (kind of like the old snake game).

For starters, I'll just have a square room and watch the workers walk around that.  I thought about trying to use a line graph with something like [Highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/#home), but it feels like I'm really bending the linechart to fit my needs.

Is there a mapping framework out there?

I'm game for either javascript, Ruby on Rails, or HTML5 solutions.

Comment: What do you think about this HTML5 wind visualization? http://hint.fm/wind/

Comment: That definitely has some potential.  Do you know if there is some documentation on what they did there? (sorry if I missed an obvious link)

Comment: http://vimeo.com/48625144, you can pretty much reconstruct the methodology. You would probably have to use a canvas for a web app.